# MySQL - Executing intensive queries on live server

Tags: mysql, database, large-data, myisam, large-data-volumes

I'm having some issues dealing with updating and inserting millions of row in a MySQL Database.  I need to flag 50 million rows in Table A, insert some data from the marked 50 million rows into Table B, then update those same 50 million rows in Table A again.  There are about 130 million rows in Table A and 80 million in Table B.

This needs to happen on a live server without denying access to other queries from the website.  The problem is while this stored procedure is running, other queries from the website end up locked and the HTTP request times out.

Here's gist of the SP, a little simplified for illustration purposes:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MyProcedure`(  
  totalLimit  int
)
BEGIN
  SET @totalLimit = totalLimit; 
  /* Prepare new rows to be issued */
  PREPARE STMT FROM 'UPDATE tableA SET `status` = "Being-Issued" WHERE `status` = "Available" LIMIT ?';
  EXECUTE STMT USING @totalLimit;
  /* Insert new rows for usage into tableB */
  INSERT INTO tableB (/* my fields */)
    SELECT /* some values from TableA */ 
    FROM tableA
    WHERE `status` = "Being-Issued";
  /* Set rows as being issued */
  UPDATE tableB SET `status` = 'Issued' WHERE `status` = 'Being-Issued';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Which database engine do these tables use?

Comment: The `status` could also be turned into `tinyint` or `char(1)`. Updating long char fields is slower.

Comment: These are MyISAM tables, and the status field is actually an enum with 3 possible values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?  It basically calls the original stored procedure in a loop until the total amount needed is reached, and having a sleep period in between calls (like 2 seconds) to allow other queries to process.

`increment` is the amount to do at one time (using 10,000 in this case)
`totalLimit` is the total amount to be processed
`sleepSec` is the amount of time to rest between calls

```
BEGIN
SET @x = 0;
REPEAT
    SELECT SLEEP(sleepSec);
    SET @x = @x + increment;
    CALL OriginalProcedure( increment );

    UNTIL @x >= totalLimit
END REPEAT;
END$$
```

Obviously it could use a little math to make sure the increment doesn't go over the total limit if its not evenly divisible, but it appears to work (by work I mean allow other queries to still be processed from web requests), and seems to be faster overall as well.

Any insight here?  Is this a good idea?  Bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Processing 50M rows three times will be slow irrespective of what you're doing.

Make sure your updates are affecting smaller-sized, disjoint sets. And execute each of them one by one, rather than each and every one of them within the same transaction.

If you're doing this already and MySQL is misbehaving, try this slight tweak to your code:

```
create a temporary table

begin

insert into tmp_table
select your stuff
limit ?
for update

do your update on A using tmp_table

commit

begin
do your insert on B using tmp_table
do your update on A using tmp_table
commit
```

this should keep locks for a minimal time.

Comment: That makes sense to break it into smaller processes.  I actually created a stored procedure that is running the other one multiple times in smaller chucks and it seems to be working a lot better (ie: running the original stored procedure for chunks of 10,000 until 5,000,000 is reached in total.)  Seems to be successfully keeping the locks for a shorter time and allows other queries to get processed.

Comment: " I actually created a stored procedure that is running the other one multiple times in smaller chucks" -- but that would run the whole thing in a single transaction, no? (which is precisely my point...)

Comment: Hmm, that does make sense.  My main concern is locking everything up so that the website can't use the database.  Can you check out the answer I posted and let me know what you think?  It seems to be working very well, but you're right... since its still in a stored procedure it would be within one transaction, but it doesn't seem to be keeping locks on the tables (which is good for me).  Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: To be quite frank, I'm unsure how MySQL will deal with it. It might work. I just know for a fact that, when processed in such a way, Postgres will process the whole thing in a single transaction, and lock things accordingly. (They've yet to implement stored procedures -- in particular async transactions -- for good reasons.)